# undefind value getting textbox with id as an array

Tags: jquery

I have to get value from textbox its name as an array.but i get response as undefined.

```
<input id="text[0][0]" type="text" value="" class="form-control label text-center" placeholder=" 1" style="">
<button>Text Box Value</button>
```

I tried jquery code

```
var button = $("button")
button.on("click", function(){
   var cell= $("#text[0][0]").val()
   alert(cell)
}))
```

Comment: Try `document.getElementById('text[0][0]').value`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - help needed on ID selector when id is an array type notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254407/jquery-help-needed-on-id-selector-when-id-is-an-array-type-notation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find DOM element by ID when ID contains square brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239095/find-dom-element-by-id-when-id-contains-square-brackets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\\` to escape square bracket in jquery selector

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/

```js
var button = $("button")
button.on("click", function() {
  var cell = $("#text\\[0\\]\\[0\\]").val()
  alert(cell)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="text[0][0]" type="text" value="1">
<button>Text Box Value</button>
```

**Note** `document.getElementById('text[0][0]')` works without escaping square brackets

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follow using Javascript.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     var button = $("button");
     button.on("click", function(){
        var cell= document.getElementById('text[0][0]').value
        alert(cell)
     })
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="text[0][0]" type="text" value="" class="form-control label text-center" placeholder=" 1" style="">
<button>Text Box Value</button>
```